# Common way to inverse a double value

Tags: dart, math

I need to create an inverse function that would flip double values: x/y = y/x

```
inverseDouble(1.2) // 0.83
inverseDouble(0.2) // 5
inverseDouble(6.0) // 0.17
```

I didn't find any solutions (maybe because I'm not an English speaker and don't know how to google this). By the way, are there any easy solutions to do this? **I'm using Dart**. Solutions using any programming language would be acceptable. I'd also appreciate even any tips or ideas about where and what to look for. Thank you.

Comment: In your software environment, given `x`, is it not possible to compute `1.0 / x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about a mathematcal solution. The inverse of a number is always one divided by that number.

Look this execution in python:

```py
>>> 1/1.2
0.8333333333333334
>>> 1/5.0
0.2
>>> 1/6.0
0.16666666666666666
```

In dart you can implement this function that way:

```dart
void main() {
  print(inverseDouble(1.2));
  print(inverseDouble(0.2));
  print(inverseDouble(6.0));
}

double inverseDouble(double number)=>1/number;
```

And the result is:

```js
0.8333333333333334
5
0.16666666666666666
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro in math, but isn't an inverse of a fraction 1/fraction?

So the function would look something like that :

```
double inverseDouble(double nb){
return 1/nb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `dart:math` for that, note that `1/x` is `x⁻¹`, or `pow(x, -1)`:

```dart
import 'dart:math' show pow;

void main() {
  print(pow(1.2, -1)); // 0.8333333333333334
  print(pow(0.2, -1)); // 5
  print(pow(6.0, -1)); // 0.16666666666666666
}
```

Why make it simple when we can make it complicated

Comment: Yes, you can obfuscate anything, and make it slower!